# Cant import package

Tags: python, kivy, qpython

I'm trying to create kivy programm with QPython and it's working fine, but when I try to import modules that I installed via pip

```
# qpy:2
# qpy:kivy
#
# for example - vk
# vk provides instruments
# to work with vk.com API
# 

import vk
```

(I launched my programm using Kivy Launcher app)

An error occurs:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/myapp/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-10-25_16.txt
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (13 instead of 14)
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2016, 23:30:13) 
[GCC 4.8]
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr: File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:    import vk
[WARNING           ] stderr: ImportError: No module named vk
```

How can I install third-party package into kivy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `Python-for-android` *!=* `pip`, nor the launcher which may be the output if you set things right.

However, read the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/launcher) and if you understand it, you can build your own launcher. This way you can put into a custom launcher any desired package hypothetically.

If the package isn't pure python (requires a compilation), you'll need to check if there's a [recipe](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes) for that. If not, either [write one](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/), or no package. ^^

Comment: I found some information about load() method using *.kex files can this help me?

Comment: @EugeneErshov What load()?

Comment: @EugeneErshov Theoretically it can be used, but you still need to compile it, which isn't supported in this way now. You could probably make an app and rip the compiled stuff out of it, but that's an overkill with the exts. You could just put it in the folder where `main.py` is as for a casual pure-python package. But making the whole new launcher is far easier and well... simpler.

Comment: I took compiled package from builded app (I used buildozer and included my package into it) I still can't understand what do you mean when you are talking about building new launcher. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I did just put this compiled package and depending package to the *.main folder and it worked! I tried to do this for several days with weired methods -- so easy

Comment: @EugeneErshov well, go to that link in my answer, there's a whole documentation how to build your own launcher (own Kivy Launcher android application with your own packages) only with `--launcher` switch, so that you don't need to copy&paste stuff this way :)